# 2.8: Disable mipmaps, view textures

Tags: texturing

Up until 2.8, I was able to disable mipmapping in the preferences (which for some reason, disabled texture filtering), however this option is now unfortunately missing. I understand I can use nodes to create unfiltered renders but I need this for pixel-perfect editing as the models will be exported.

Another issue I have it that textures now longer show up in 'look dev' mode without a material. (previously alt-z).

Until I can fix these, I have to revert to 2.79a. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: You can set the texture interpolation on the image node to closest and to disable antialiasing set the pixel filter to box (Render tab > Film). I'm not quite sure what your issue with textures in look dev mode is, if you connect a texture node with your material it will be displayed.

Comment: Hello. Thank you for your comment, however; please read my post carefully. I know how to use nodes and how to disable texture filtering for renders. I am speaking about unfiltered textures in regular edit mode.

Comment: I was looking the same thing but I found this link: https://blenderartists.org/t/2-8-where-is-mipmaps-option-for-working-with-pixel-art/1138417 I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Under the shading tab, add an environment texture and set it to closest and connect the node up.